# R: Random sampling from a Normal, Absolute Values

Tags: r

I am interested in the following question: generate 100 random samples, each of size 100 from N(0,1). In each sample, find the absolute mean, e.g. (1/100)*sum(abs(x)) for all x in the sample. Here's how I'm going about it:

```
set.seed(124)

N <- 100

samples <- rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=1)

A <- function(x,N){
  (1/N)*sum(abs(x))
}

result <- sapply(samples, A, N)

print(result)
print(mean(result))
print(var(result))
```

But this seems to only be taking a single size-100 random sample. How can I fix my code? And how can I generate a plot of the mean and variance of `result` as `N` varies? Do I have to use a `for` loop, or is there a better way to do this in R?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: You have called `rnorm` exactly once. That means you have exactly one sample of 100 random numbers.

Comment: I see - thank you. What if I did two `sapply`?

`N <- 100`
`NSamp <- c(1:N)`
`takesample <- function(N) {
  x <- rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=1)
}`
`samples <- sapply(NSamp, takesample(N))`

`A <- function(x,N){
  (1/N)*sum(abs(x))
}`

`result <- sapply(samples, A, N)`

Comment: I have added some working code below. Cheers!

Comment: Use function replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
runs <- 100;
rfun <- rnorm;
size <- 100;
m <- double(0)
for (i in 1:runs) m[i] =  mean(rfun(size));
```

You now have a 100 means from 100 samples of size 100 each. I have written it so you can play around with distributions other than normal if you wish.

Comment: I thought the idea in R was to try to apply functions over vectors instead of using loops? (Not saying this is correct, just trying to get it straight in my head)

Comment: Whatever is simplest route to getting the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more functional. Is it closer to what you want?

```
sample_hundo <- function() { rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd=1) }
funny_normalize <- function(sample.vec) { sum(abs(sample.vec)) / length(sample.vec) }

replicate(10, funny_normalize(sample_hundo()))
```

From `?sapply`:

> ‘replicate’ is a wrapper for the common use of ‘sapply’ for
>        repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve
>        random number generation).

Comment: That's quite nice!

But isn't this only doing 10 replications? Furthermore, shouldn't I have to store the result in some matrix (data frame?)

Comment: It is definitely only doing 10 replications. You should be able to swap that out as you need. Also, matrices, data frames, and vectors are all different data types for different jobs. This question and answer can't tell you which one is best for your application.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a matrix? Each column represent a run and each column contains 100 values from N(0,1). You should try to avoid loops.

```
runs <- 200; size <- 100
sample_mat <- matrix(rnorm(runs*size, mean = 0, sd = 1), ncol = runs)
colMeans(abs(sample_mat))
```

Comment: Thank you..I think these are 200 samples, each of size 100, right? I'm not quite sure why you have `runs*size` in the first argument of `rnorm`: shouldn't it be just `size`? We want 100 runs, each of size 100.

Comment: And what precisely does `colMeans` do? Sorry for the double post

Comment: @aridneptune It calculates the mean of each column.

Comment: OK, got it - but why is `rnorm`'s argument `runs*size` instead of just `size`?

Comment: @aridneptune because each column represents a different sample.